# Reputation graph showing wrong number

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-graph

There's a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653/leora?tab=topactivity) on Stack Overflow who currently has 17,745 reputation, but the reputation graph shows a different number:

[image]

Comment: Shows the same on their [network rep graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/3246/leora?tab=reputation) (which shows their rep yesterday as 22k+). Maybe there was a recalc from removed user/suspicious voting/something else that hasn't updated on the graphs?

Answer (score 2):

I can't say what the issue was, but whatever it was it seems to have been resolved. Looking at [the user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653/leora?tab=topactivity) now, the total reputation number on the left seems to have caught up to the number in the graph:

[image: Screenshot of reputation graph on user's profile]

Comment: But if you go all the way to the right on the line, it is now 16 lower on the graph than the number.

Comment: @Stormblessed That seems to be an issue with every user whose graph isn't flat enough. I guess it's just not possible to get to the very end of the line. On the other hand, I did find [another user](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson?tab=topactivity) who has more reputation in the graph than in the total number, but unlike the case here it's only a slight difference.

Comment: On [my profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/102999/stormblessed) it goes all the way and shows the current total correctly

Comment: @Stormblessed Your graph is flat at the end. so even without the last bit the number would be the same.